# editable column in kendo mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to make editable column in kendo mvc grid

In kendo

```
columns.Bound(c => c.g).EditorTemplateName("MyTemplate");
```

in folder Shared/EditorTemplates in file MyTemplate.cshtml

```
@model MyModel
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(c=>c.g)
)
```

But my solution isnt correct. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the ["Editable" option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder#methods-Editable) of the Grid? Basically you should enable this option and than disable the editing for the desired columns from the DataSource or using "[ScaffoldColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)" attribute set to false:

```
.Model(model=> {
  model.Field(m => m.ProductName).Editable(false);
})
```

Comment: No. because in kendogrid I use another model

Comment: Apologize if I was not clear enought - this option is mandatory if you need to edit the Grid records. Also the Grid always pass the current field type to the editor template - so you don't have to worry about it.